# Jackson map different unwrapped elements in same POJO

Tags: java, xml-parsing, jackson

I am trying to parse some XML to Java, but this XML is a big mess.

So looks like Jackson only read the last object of each type and the array size of each type has only one object.

Edit.: This is what i am trying to do (debug and see the values of form object):

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
        Form form  = mapper.readValue(getXml(), Form.class);
    }

    public static String getXml() {

        return "<forms>\n"
            + "    <circles><x>1</x></circles>\n"
            + "    <squares><x>1</x></squares>\n"
            + "    <squares><x>1</x></squares>\n"
            + "    <circles><x>1</x></circles>\n"
            + "    <squares><x>1</x></squares>\n"
            + "</forms>";

    }

}

@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "forms")
class Form {

    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "circles", isAttribute = false)
    private List<Circle> circles;

    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "squares", isAttribute = false)
    private List<Square> squares;

    public List<Circle> getCircles() {
        return circles;
    }

    public void setCircles(List<Circle> circles) {
        this.circles = circles;
    }

    public List<Square> getSquares() {
        return squares;
    }

    public void setSquares(List<Square> squares) {
        this.squares = squares;
    }

}

@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "circles")
class Circle {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = false)
    private String x;

    public String getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(String x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

}

@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "squares")
class Square {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = false)
    private String x;

    public String getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(String x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to include bit more information: it is not clear what and how you are doing, exactly. So bit of Java code showing usage would be helpful. But I agree in that the code as shown is a mess, and it may not be easy to map that into anything usable. But you could try using `@JsonAnySetter`, and/or special handling in setter-methods for those disjoint `points` and `squares` elements.

Comment: Any ideia about extra info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize the list.

```
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "circles", isAttribute = false)
    private final List<Circle> circles = new ArrayList<>();
```

Rather than replace, add all elements.

```
    public void setCircles(List<Circle> circles) {
        this.circles.addAll(circles);
    }
```

This is the trick. Thanks to @StaxMan.

Answer (score 0):

Since lists are non-consecutive, what happens is that they will get separately created, so that last run overrides earlier. You may be able to resolve this by implementing `setCircles` (etc) to append to List, not replace it.